# Calculation of standard deviation of the mean changes from the p-value or z-value of the Wilcoxon test

Tags: standard-deviation, meta-analysis, effect-size, wilcoxon-signed-rank, z-statistic

I am conducting a meta-analysis of observational studies without a control group that compared a parameter's value before and after an operation. All included studies have reported their results as pre-and-postoperative mean ± standard deviation and statistical analysis p-value. While it is possible to determine the standard deviation of the mean changes from the p-value of the paired t-test; however, some of the included studies have used the Wilcoxon test to compare pre-and-postoperative data. How can I calculate the standard deviation of the mean changes from the p-value or z-value of the Wilcoxon test in these studies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without additional information, it's not possible.

Imagine a set of paired pre- and post- values with some particular $Z_S=\frac{S-\mu_S}{\sigma_S}$ where $S$ is whichever version of the signed rank statistic is your favourite.

a. Take the set of post$-$pre differences and double them. The signed rank statistic, $S$ and the $Z$ value will be the same.

b. Take the set of post$-$pre differences and *cube* them. The statistic and its $Z$ value will be unchanged.

c. Take the set of post$-$pre differences and take the hyperbolic arc sin of each of them ($\operatorname{asinh}(d) = \log(d+\sqrt{d^2+1})$). The statistic and its $Z$ value are again unchanged.

d. Take the set of post$-$pre differences and add 100 to the positive ones and subtract 100 from the negative ones. Same thing!

If this information is unfamiliar to you, start with a small set of data and *actually try these* and see.

Indeed apply whatever other transformation of the values of $d$ that leaves the ranks of $|d|$ and their signs unaltered that you wish to the set of pair-differences. Same $S$, same $Z$ every time. So going back from $Z$ to $\bar{d}$ or its standard error is not possible. (Similarly with p-values, whether based on the $Z$-value or on the exact test.)

This is because the value of $S$ depends *only on the ranks and signs of the differences*, and transformations like those above leave the signed ranks unaltered.

Since many (indeed infinitely many) distinct situations get you back to the same $Z_S$ value, you have no way to "go back" to the mean of post$-$pre. There's simply nothing to be done. It's not a reversible operation.

Example in R. First some post-pre differences and the signed rank test:

```
d=c(0.64, 1, -0.24, -1.34, 0.96, 0.22, -0.72, 1.24, -0.89, -0.36)

wilcox.test(d)

        Wilcoxon signed rank exact test

data:  d
V = 29, p-value = 0.9219
alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 0
```

Now let's transform the differences in several ways that won't change the signed ranks (some extraneous lines of output are removed for brevity):

```
 wilcox.test(d*2)
 V = 29, p-value = 0.9219

 wilcox.test(d^3)
 V = 29, p-value = 0.9219

 wilcox.test(asinh(d))
 V = 29, p-value = 0.9219

 wilcox.test(ifelse(d>0,d+100,d-100))
 V = 29, p-value = 0.9219
```

(In that last case the possibility of a d=0 was ignored because there were no 0-differences in the data; if they occur, you'd need to make sure you left those as-is.)

All of these will have different $\bar{d}$ and a different standard error of the mean difference; which one should we go back to?